# Bootstrap menu (nav) collapse horizontally instead of vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]i'm using this Html /css for and the menu(bootstrap nav ) and it is always horizontal on a small screen / mobile device. that I want it / need it to be vertical.i'm using bootstrap 3.2

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="home/index" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="../../Images/Logo.gif" alt="" class=" left img-rounded img-responsive noborder " />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-right  nav-pills navbar-right ">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("1", "Index", "ContactUs")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("2", "Allpictuers", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("3", "Index", "Courses")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("4", "Events", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("5", "OurStafMembers", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("6", "Index", "Abouts")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("7", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("8", "Index", "English")</li>
                @*<li>>@Html.ActionLink("Thisis _Layout", "Index", "English")</li>*@

                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <li>  @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "admin")</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is the render Html:

> /  ...

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-right  nav-pills ">
                <li><a href="/ContactUs">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Allpictuers">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Courses">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Events">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/OurStafMembers">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Abouts">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="/English">8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What, exactly, is horizontal? Please show a demo or at least a screen shot.

Comment: all the links (1,2,3, ect' ) are displaying horizontal on a small screen (instead of vertical )

Comment: I have added an image to my original Q.

Comment: Please show rendered HTML and not your server-side code. Bootstrap doesn't care about that.

Comment: how is the size of the image since the default size is 50px height?

Comment: The image is 100 px, but I have the same problem with or without the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:** (Use `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` instead of nav-pills and friends.)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=""/></a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:2%;">
                <li><a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: the nav-stacked on a wide screen also in your Demo keep the menu open and vertical. in a wide screen I need it to be  horizontal

Comment: Then you should use <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> instead of nav-pills and friend : look, I updated my script and updated demo :D

Comment: Yes , it look like nav-pills fix the problem .Please  update you nswer so I can mark it

Comment: are you sure that's what you want and you feel solved successfully?

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right "  style="padding-right:2%;"> It look like . thanks .

Comment: no problem, I learn much too about nav-pills and friends :D thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just add the class `nav-stacked`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right  nav-pills nav-stacked">
 ...
</ul>
```

you also have `navbar-right` twice.. remove that

Comment: nav-stacked is just keeping it open all time and include wide screen

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap nav links are stacked by default for mobile. My best guess is that your rendered HTML doesn't have anchors inside the list items. Bootstrap uses the anchors as CSS targets, not the list items.

If your output looks like this it will work as expected with no changes:

```
<li><a href="#">Link text</a></li>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z7m43nsz/)**